# Trouble with getting configuration file FCM

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, google-play-services

I create application in firebase console, filled application name and fingertrip fileds. Then i try download configuration file google-service.gson and getting message "Failed-Forbidden". What is it and what am I supposed to do?

Comment: Have you tried using an incognito window or other browsers like what was mentioned [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/firebase-talk/FBIIQmYSKNU/0TulBsz5FwAJ)?

Comment: Thanks! I read your article and found the answer there. Problem was in two google accounts! Need exit from one before getting configuration file.

Answer (score 1):

Problem was in two google accounts. Need exit from one before getting configuration file.